# Uploading Data to Solr with Data import handler

Tags: xml, solr, wikipedia, dataimporthandler

Hi I am struggling to upload my data onto solr with the data import handler. What I am doing is starting a solr server using the command in the server folder

```
solr start
```

This then allows me to open up a localhost on my computer where a core that I have previously set up is displayed.

[image: Screenshot of solr running on computer]

I have then edited the files solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

In solrconfig.xml I have put the following lines of code in

```
<lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*.jar" /> 

<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

and

```
<requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
</lst>
```

In schema.xml (renamed from the managed-schema file) I added

```
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="revision" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="user" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="userId" type="pint" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Then I created a data-config.xml file with the following code

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="FileDataSource" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<document>
    <entity name="page"
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            stream="true"
            forEach="/mediawiki/page"
            url="/Volumes/BACKUP/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml"
            transformer="RegexTransformer,DateFormatTransformer"
            >
        <field column="id" xpath="/mediawiki/page/id" />
        <field column="title" xpath="/mediawiki/page/title" />
        <field column="revision" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/id" />
        <field column="user" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/contributor/username" />
        <field column="userId" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/contributor/id" />
        <field column="text" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/text" />
        <field column="timestamp" xpath="/mediawiki/page/revision/timestamp" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'" />
        <field column="$skipDoc" regex="^#REDIRECT .*" replaceWith="true" souceColName="text"/>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Here the xml I wish to index is stored on an external harddrive on my computer. All seems to be working well until I type the following into my browser

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/wiki/dataimport?command=full-import
```

and the following is shown

[image: full-import]
[image: logging]

Does anyone know how to fix this? I'm using solr 7.7 and all the questions on Stackoverflow seem to be for earlier versions. The tutorial I am trying to follow is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VkFQTqrRYo&t=310s which is old so I think that's why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I'd think there'd be a more complete log that shows the actual reason for why it can't add the documents - since the error is coming from the writer, initial guess is that it can't write the index file or transaction log to the disk for some reason.

Comment: @matLindh do you have any idea where I would go to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all i needed to do was to change in solrconfig.xml :

`<updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema" default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"`

(false instead of true)

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all...The clasNotFoundException...Check your class path , looks like DataImportHandler is not on your classpath...

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```

After the configuration changes restart the jetty server.

Comment: That still didn't fix the problem!! Ended up deleting Solr off my computer completely and reinstalling 7.6.0 and everything works fine other than now my documents are failing to be uploaded even though they are being indexed

Comment: I made an edit to the post to show the new error. Also I am now using Solr 7.6 now